# Can you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus with the variable inside the integrand?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was wondering if I can apply the FTOC: $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(t) } dt \right) =f(x)$ to an implicit function with the variable being differentiated implicit in the function.

For example: $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \int _{ a }^{ x }{ xf(t) } dt \right)$ or any function in the form: $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(x,t)f(t) } dt \right) $ and if so, what would we get.

Comment: Note $\int_a^x x f(t) \mathop{dt} = x \int_a^x f(t)\mathop{dt}$

Comment: Would this be the same if we have say: $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(x,t)f(t) } dt \right) $ such as $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \int _{ a }^{ x }{ \sqrt { 1+xt } f(t) } dt \right) $ or would we have to deal with it otherwise?

Comment: May be simply $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_a^x f(x,t)dt)$.

Comment: "wander" $\ne$ "wonder".

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics any question of the form:

> Can we do X?

always has the answer:

> If you have proven that you can.

In particular if you ask:

> Can you apply theorem X to Y?

the answer is just:

> As long as Y satisfies the conditions required by theorem X.

In your case, the fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply when the integrand involves the limit of integration.

You may be wondering whether the theorem can somehow be extended to cover that case. The simple answer is that it cannot, and nothing more can be said unless we know exactly what kind of integrand it is.

Comment: First, thanks for replying, Second, if I may rephrase my question, we know by the FTOC that if g is a function of x: $g(x)=\int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(t)dt } $ , then $g'(x)=f(x)$ , so my question would be if instead $h(x)=\int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(x,t)dt } $, would $h'(x)=f(x,x)$ similarly as we regard x as a constant inside the integral?.

Comment: So for example if $h(x)=\int _{ a }^{ x }{ \sqrt { 1+xt } f(t)dt } $, is it true that we say $h'(x)=\sqrt { 1+x^{ 2 } } f(x)$?

Comment: @AspiringMat: Of course not, since as I said the conditions required by the theorem are not satisfied. You should always try small examples yourself! If you find counter-examples, you know it is wrong. If you don't, it doesn't mean it is right but may help you think of why it is right (if it really is right). In this case.. what is the simplest integral you can think of with $x$ in both the integrand and the limit of integration?

Comment: I am sorry if I irritated you in some way, and thank you I think I got it. The simplest example if $\int _{ a }^{ x }{ xf(t)dt } $, and since x is irrelevant of t we can take it out to get $x\int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(t)dt } $. If I differentiate wrt x, I get $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( x\int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(t)dt }  \right) =xf(x)+\int _{ a }^{ x }{ f(t) } dt$ which is not the same as xf(x) as long as $x\neq a$.

Comment: @AspiringMat: No you didn't irritate me, but I am earnestly telling you to always check every tiny detail of the conditions required for a theorem. It is often overlooked by many students who just want the answer and not understand the logical reasoning completely. As for the simplest example, I would give $\int_0^x x\ dt = [xt]_0^x = x^2$ which when differentiate with respect to $x$ gives $2x$, not $x$.

Comment: @AspiringMat: As for your example, your last phrase is not correct. It may be that $x \ne a$ but $\int_a^x f(t)\ dt = 0$. However, you got the idea, that if that integral is not zero then it gives a desired counter-example.

Answer (score 8):

By definition
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(x,t)dt=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[\int_a^{x+\Delta x}f(x+\Delta x,t)dt-\int_a^x f(x,t)dt\right]$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[\int_a^{x+\Delta x}\left(f(x,t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x\right)dt-\int_a^x f(x,t)dt\right]$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[\int_a^{x+\Delta x}f(x,t)dt-\int_a^x f(x,t)dt + \int_a^{x+\Delta x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x dt\right]$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[\int_x^{x+\Delta x}f(x,t)dt + \int_a^{x+\Delta x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x dt\right]$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[f(x,x)\Delta x + \Delta x \int_a^{x+\Delta x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dt\right]$$
$$=f(x,x)+\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \int_a^{x+\Delta x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dt$$
$$=f(x,x)+\int_a^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$

In conclusion, you will only get the first term if you apply the FTOC blindly. Because the integrand contains $x$, you will have the second extra term.

Comment: Where did $\int_x^{x+\Delta x}f(x,t)dt=f(x,x)\Delta$ come from?