# Showing $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ using recursion property of $\Gamma(x)$

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function

From the book "Asymptotic Analysis and Perturbation Theory" by William Paulsen,

> **Problem 23 p.67.**
>
> Show that $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$.
>
> Hint: First use the recursion property of $\Gamma(x)$ to show that, for $n$ an integer $>1$,
> $$\frac{\Gamma'(n)}{\Gamma(n)}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}+\Gamma'(1)$$
>
> Then use Stirling's formula to show that,
> $$\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\sim \ln(x)-\frac{1}{2x}+\cdots\ \text{as}\ x\to\infty$$

I did some searching and found many posts using the Leibniz integral rule to show $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ which I understand, but I cannot seem to finish the problem using the hints they give. Here is my attempt.

We know $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. Taking the logarithmic derivative,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\Gamma'(n)}{\Gamma(n)}&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}\left(\ln(n-1)!\right) \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}\left(\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)\right)\right) \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\ln\left(n-k\right)\right) \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{n-k}\right)
\end{align*}$$
Writing out the terms,
$$\frac{\Gamma'(n)}{\Gamma(n)}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}$$
Though there is some resembelnce, this does not agree with the hint as I am missing the $\Gamma'(1)$ term. I think the problem comes from when I took the derivative but I don't know the exact issue. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The derivative of a sum, where the upper limit of the sum involves the variable you differentiate with respect to?  Needs much more work to do that.

Comment: @GEdgar. Thanks for the clarification. I can't just take derivatives of integers right?

Comment: It's not the integers that are the problem, it's the $n - 1$ in the top of the sum. We can't just willy-nilly interchange the sum and the derivative operator.

Comment: @prets. I see, that makes sense. From what I'm reading I need to use some difference operator, which I'm not familiar with. But I am still curious on how that could be done. Are you willing to write an answer?

Comment: Maybe seeing why this is trouble will be easier from the perspective of integrals. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1832752), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the recursion property $\Gamma(x + 1) = x \Gamma(x)$,
$$\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} \log\bigl( (x-1) \Gamma(x-1) \bigr) = \frac{1}{x - 1} + \frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x - 1)).$$
Now repeat this many times until we have
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)} &= \frac{1}{x - 1} + \frac{1}{x - 2} + \frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x - 2)) \\
&= \dots = \frac{1}{x - 1} + \frac{1}{x - 2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2} + 1 + \frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x - (n - 1))).
\end{align*}$$
This last expression is also (just by chain rule/viewing the logarithmic derivative as what it is)
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log(\Gamma(x - (n - 1))) = \frac{\Gamma'(x - (n - 1))}{\Gamma(x - (n - 1))}. 
$$
Now evaluate everything at $x = n$ and remember $\Gamma(1) = 1$.